# Android layouts in iOS

Tags: ios, layout

I'm an Android developer learning iOS, I'm trying to add "sections" in a detail view of my app, I want to achieve something like the following image:

[image]

In Android I'd probably define three layouts and inside each one put the controls that I needed. I couldn't find something like a layout, how would these sections be implemented in iOS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use three different `UIView`s and put all those in one `UIView` that takes up the entire screen.

You would put all the UI elements (text, buttons, etc) you want in each section in one of the three `UIView` sections you created, just like the layouts in Android.